# Forwarding Multiple port to Single port using nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to proxy pass all requests coming from a series of ports into single port.
I am able to proxy pass a single port to another like so:

```
server {
    listen 3333;
    server_name test.in *.test.in;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://10.1.1.2:5479/;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

So when I try test.in:3333 it redirects to 10.1.1.2:5479.

In the same way I need to proxy pass these:

```
test.in 4440 to 10.1.1.2:5479
test.in 4441 to 10.1.1.2:5479  
test.in 4442 to 10.1.1.2:5479
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting up multiple `server` blocks, similar to the one in your example, listening on the different ports (4440, 4441, and 4442) and having an identical proxy_pass configuration section.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 4440;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://10.1.1.2:5479/;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
server {
    listen 4441;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://10.1.1.2:5479/;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
server {
    listen 4442;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://10.1.1.2:5479/;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

It's also working...

```
server {
    listen 4442;
    listen 4441;
    listen 4443;
    listen 4444;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://10.1.1.2:5479/;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```